# Calculate Mandelbrot set without complex objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, complex-numbers, mandelbrot

I am trying to calculate the Mandelbrot set in Python 3.6 and  i don't want to use the complex objects to calculate it. Does anybody have a `getIterationCount(x, y)` function?

I tried to rewrite java code to python but it didn't work.

```py
def getIterationCount(x, y):
    maxiter = 100
    z = complexe(x, y)
    c = z
    for n in range(0, maxiter):
        if abs(z) > 2:
            return n
        z = z*z + c
    return maxiter
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to write your own code to square and sum your own representations of complex numbers?

Comment: Yes, i want to calulate the fundamental z = z² + c without complexe numbers

Comment: After about 15 seconds of googling: [Example: Class for complex numbers](http://hplgit.github.io/primer.html/doc/pub/class/._class-solarized005.html)

Comment: You just do the same thing, but write out what happens to the real and imaginary parts separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can write it for you if you mean to work only with real numbers:

```
def getIterationCount(ca,cb):
    maxiter = 100
    za, zb = ca,cb
    for n in range(0, maxiter):
        if za**2+zb**2 > 4:
            return n
        za, zb = za*za - zb*zb + ca, 2*za*zb + cb

    return maxiter
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @user11392757 You are welcome. Please consider accepting the answer.

Comment: When I am generating an image with this function its distorted and blurred. Do you know why this happens ?

Comment: Please give your source code for that.

Comment: Sorry, there was a mistake in my program. The assignment to zb was called with the updated za, that's wrong. I've corrected this.

Comment: Thanks, I will test it.